# Python Equilibrium Reaction Constants

Tags: python

I am trying to code a simple equilibrium reaction where
[A]+[B] <-> [C] + [D]

```
[A]=50
[B]=50
[C]=50
[D]=50

k1 (forward)= 1

k-1 (reverse)= .5
```

Thank you

Comment: You should post whatever Python code you tried out. `[A]=50` isn't valid Python code, and neither is `k1 (forward)= 1`. That's just a text rendering of some mathematical and chemical notation.

Comment: We are not chemists (or chemistry students) so we don't know what formulae you are trying to translate into code!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is not very clear,
but i guess you would like to have a program that calculates the equilibrium concentrations of the reaction.
I also suppose that the input data you gave, `[A]`, ..., `[D]`, correspond to the initial concentrations.

Assuming that, the first thing I would advise you - before writing any line of code,
is to establish the formula that gives the equilibrium concentrations; and *then* implement it.

So, let's do first a bit of chemistry and maths :)
(I've based my reasoning on this course: http://cinet.chim.pagesperso-orange.fr/cours/chap3.html#L18704)

First, the extent at equilibrium is:

```
xe = [A]0-[A]∞ = [B]0-[B]∞ = [C]∞-[C]0 = [D]∞-[D]0   (1)
```

Also at equilibrium, you have the *Law of Mass Action*:

```
K(constant) = k1/k-1 = [C]∞⋅[D]∞/[A]∞⋅[B]∞   (2)
```

You can express the constant `K` as a function of `[A]∞`,
replacing `[B]∞`, `[C]∞` and `[D]∞` in (2) using equations in (1):

```
[B]∞ = [B]0 + [A]∞ - [A]0
[C]∞ = [C]0 + [A]0 - [A]∞
[D]∞ = [D]0 + [A]0 - [A]∞

K = ([C]0+[A]0-[A]∞)⋅([D]0+[A]0-[A]∞)/[A]∞⋅([B]0+[A]∞-[A]0)   (3)
```

Where (3) can be seen as a second degree equation:

```
x := [A]∞
(K-1)⋅x2 + [2⋅[A]0 + [C]0 + [D]0 + K⋅([B]0-[A]0)]⋅x - [[A]0⋅([A]0+[C]0+[D]0) + [C]0⋅[D]0] = 0
```

Similarly or by symmetry, you could have done the same for `[B]∞`, `[C]∞` or `[D]∞`.
But it is easier to reuse (1).

Now, we can see better how to proceed. Let's code it!

```py
import math

# Solve the quadratic equation a⋅x² + b⋅x + c = 0
def solve_2nd_degree_equation(a, b, c):
    discriminant = (b ** 2) - (4 * a * c)
    solution_1 = (-b - math.sqrt(discriminant)) / (2 * a)
    solution_2 = (-b + math.sqrt(discriminant)) / (2 * a)
    return [solution_1, solution_2]
```

The function above will be used for solving second degree equations.

```py
class EquilibriumReactionProblem(object):
    def __init__(self, a0, b0, c0, d0, k_forward, k_reverse):
        self.a0 = a0
        self.b0 = b0
        self.c0 = c0
        self.d0 = d0
        self.k = k_forward / k_reverse

    def _compute_a_equilibrium(self):
        a = self.k - 1
        b = 2 * self.a0 + self.c0 + self.d0 + self.k * (self.b0 - self.a0)
        c = -(self.a0 * (self.a0 + self.c0 + self.d0) + self.c0 * self.d0)
        [res] = [s for s in solve_2nd_degree_equation(a, b, c) if 0 <= s]
        return round(res, 2)

    def solve(self):
        a_equilibrium = self._compute_a_equilibrium()
        b_equilibrium = self.b0 + a_equilibrium - self.a0
        c_equilibrium = self.c0 + self.a0 - a_equilibrium
        d_equilibrium = self.d0 + self.a0 - a_equilibrium
        print({
            'a_equilibrium': a_equilibrium,
            'b_equilibrium': b_equilibrium,
            'c_equilibrium': c_equilibrium,
            'd_equilibrium': d_equilibrium
        })
```

All we have to do is now to run it with the initial conditions:

```py
EquilibriumReactionProblem(
    a0=50,
    b0=50,
    c0=50,
    d0=50,
    k_forward=1,
    k_reverse=0.5
).solve()
```

```
{'a_equilibrium': 41.42, 'b_equilibrium': 41.42, 'c_equilibrium': 58.58, 'd_equilibrium': 58.58}
```

**EDIT:** You may also take advantage of [ChemPy](https://github.com/bjodah/chempy#chemical-equilibria) lib.